# The route addition failed: Cannot create a file when that file already exists

Tags: windows-server-2003, addition, routes, persistent, rras

I get this error when using c:>route add <route_and_interface_here>

This happens on a RRAS server that has a PPTP site-to-site VPN setup with demand-dialing static route. This route shows in RRAS routing table but does not show in c:>route print table which might be the first source of the problem.

Anyone seen this before? Anyone with experts-exchange account that can read the proposed answers there?

Problem might be connected with applying SP2 on Win2k3 and installing RRAS after that from RTM disk.

Answer (score 0):

Give a high route metric value then the PPtp adapter while adding the route.

There seems to be problem with windows 7 interface metric calculation.